# Retrieving mail items with Id and Outlook REST API

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

Given a list of Ids (aka ItemIds) how can we efficiently retrieve the emails with OutlookREST Api?

I tried to forge the following request.

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/MailFolders/<somefolderId>/messages?$filter=((Id eq 'firstId') or (Id eq 'secondId') or (Id eq 'thirdId'))
```

But I received a BadRequest 400 error: "The property 'Id' does not support filtering" which is very clear.

As a workaround I use the InternetMessageId (I do not care which "copy" of the email is returned). Is there a way to use the Id to achieve better performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do up to 20 individual `GET` requests for each ID in a [batch request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/batch-outlook-rest-requests). This is only available on the `beta` endpoint right now.

Something like:

```
POST https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/$batch HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer aGFwcHlnQGRr==
Host: outlook.office.com
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_myBatchId


--batch_myBatchId
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET  /api/beta/me/messages/{id1}    HTTP/1.1


--batch_myBatchId
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET  /api/beta/me/messages/{id2}    HTTP/1.1


--batch_myBatchId--
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Knowing that in beta endpoint InternetMessageId is a primary property of the Message object. To your knowledge, doing batch request for 20 items on ItemId will be significantly faster than doing a $filter with 20's 'or' statement on the 'InternetMessageId'?

Comment: I don't have any hard data, but in general I'd avoid overly complex filters like that. I'd assume gets with Ids would be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your insights.